# RegEx: get first occurrence of pattern

Tags: c#, regex

ive got a string which goes like

`[...] <a rel=\"nofollow\" class=\"username offline popupctrl\" href=\"http://....html\" title=\"T3XTT0F1ND is offline\" id=\"...\">\">\">\">"[...]`

If i set the pattern to

```
"<a rel=\"nofollow\" (.+) id=\"(.+)(?=\")"
```

i get T3XTT0F1ND">">"> instead of just T3XTT0F1ND at Groups[2].Value.
How can i set the RegEx to not only find the first possible occurrence of 'a rel="nofollow"...' but also of 'id="' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you make one more () for the title, like

```
<a rel=\"nofollow\" (.+) title=\"(.+)\" id=\"(.+)(?=\")
```

This would result in Groups[2] returning **T3XTT0F1ND is offline**.

Moreover, you meant that your **id** is equal **T3XTT0F1ND** and your Groups captures more than this? If the answer is yes then you may try the regexp below

```
<a rel=\"nofollow\" (.+) id=\"(.+)[^>]\"
```

Comment: "Shouldn't you make one more () for the title" - Whoops, this fixed it. Thanks a lot. ;)

Comment: @kojoma No problem, but the general rule is that if the answer suits you then you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for A tags where the ID attribute always follows the REL attribute. The ID value is captured into capture group 1:

```cs
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"<a\b                 # Open start tag delimiter
      [^>]*?               # Everything up to REL attrib
      \b rel=""nofollow""  # REL attrib.
      [^>]*?               # Everything up to ID attrib
      \b id=""([^""]*)""   # $1: ID attrib.
      [^>]*                # Everything up to end of start tag.
    >                      # Close start tag delimiter", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```